# How can see a list of all public comments made on Facebook by a certain account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

How can see a list of all public comments made on Facebook by a certain account? I've been searching online for a summary of all (at a minimum, public, preferably all) comments made by a specific account.

I'm asking because I'd like to check my old profiles' comment histories to decide whether the pages are worth trying to gain access to in order to deactivate or I am safe to disregard them.

Something tells me this is not a feature Facebook will make readily available, since they would like to keep even dormant accounts in order to strip them of information for profit.

Answer (score 2):

1. "Posts commented on by Mark Zuckerberg"

https://www.facebook.com/search/4/stories-commented

2. "Posts commented on by Sheryl Sandberg"

https://www.facebook.com/search/717545176/stories-commented

3. "Activity Log for Self"

https://www.facebook.com/your_old_profile/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=cluster_116